# How to access asset in a cordova plugin which has been hot code pushed by Meteor?

Tags: java, android, cordova, meteor, cordova-plugins

The Android map plugin I am bulding uses meteor assets as marker image. I open them with `context.getResources().getAssets().open(filePath);`

All assets are placed in `public` folder `(public/icons/xxx.png)`, and for a plugin to access assets, I use this path `www/application/app/icons/xxx.png`.

But I can only access the initial bundle. When a new assets bundle is pushed, the plugins still displays the old assets.

I guess that something is wrong with the way of retrieving the asset:

- what should be the path for open new asset **INSIDE** a java Cordova plugin?
- Have I to use the `getAssets()` method or something else?

Comment: Are you sure that the Cordova plugin (and its assets) is updated through Hot Code Push? IIRC only Meteor bundle (JS, CSS and assets in `public` folder) is updated.

Comment: Yep, my question concerns image placed in public folder. I will update my question.